# Include an if condition in message-box dialog code in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, conditional-statements, messagebox, messagedialog

I have a message box dialog which comes with yes no like following. I have added no button as default selected button in the code. I want to do this by checking an if condition. Based on the if condition result I want to set the default button in the message dialog. I am doing it with "MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2 "Without repeating message box dialog in an if the condition is there a way that I can set this button checking a value using an if condition inside this dialog box code.

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Selected itemis already existing , Do you want to continue adding?", "XXX", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes)
   {

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is what you want.

```
bool myCondition = true;  

if (MessageBox.Show("Selected itemis already existing , Do you want to continue adding?", "XXX", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question,myCondition? MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2:MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes)  
{  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your Default Button in a `MessageBoxDefaultButton`:

```
MessageBoxDefaultButton DefaultButton = MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1;
```

and use it:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Selected itemis already existing , Do you want to continue adding?", "XXX", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, DefaultButton) == DialogResult.Yes)
{

}
```